# Can't create Session in Asp MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC Application which is published on 2 IIS web servers (one for `debug` and one for `release`).

In this application, I use a Session variable to keep the user Login, but in the `release` server this Session definition didn't work, returning the error:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

I believe that it can only be IIS configurations, because the same code works fine on the `debug` server and in localhost, that is why I can not debug the application.

I have never made a IIS configuration before, but in my search about it, I found that there is a config for the Sessions State (see this link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc754450(v=ws.10))), which, for default, is set as `true`, and if I try to set `false`, nothing different happens.

Here's the code:

```
// POST: Auth/Login/{login}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(DTOViewModel login)
{
    try
    {
        this.Autenticar(login.Usuario, login.Password);
        Session["user"] = login.Usuario; // <---- Here is the problem
        return Json(new { url = Url.Action("Index", "User/Home") });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { erro = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Comment: so, did you change any settings on IIS as per ref link ?

Comment: i tried, but nothing changes

Comment: are you sure that login variable has the data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
Check the maximum worker process associated with the application pool. It should be 1.

Steps to check the maximum worker process:

1. Go to the application pool from left panel in IIS
2. Select application pool which is associated with your website.
3. Go to the advance setting of that application pool
4. Set the Process Model --> "maximum worker process" to 1

**Solution 2:**
Change the below setting in web.config file:

```
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
          <remove name="Session" />
          <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
        </modules>   
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi man, thanks for the help, I saw it on both IIS servers and the "maximum worker process" is already set to 1.

Comment: I have added another solution, check this works for you or not?